# jquery get the height of the submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have the `<ul>` tag as below. When clicked on the anchor link it should display a div with the ul list items underneath. On the click function of anchor tag, I need to get the complete height of the div (in fact the height of the ul with li items), the submenu

```
<ul>
<li>
<a></a>
<div>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

The html code is as below:

```
<ul class="menu level-1 plain" id="header-menu">
    @{
        var i = 1; //Used for submenu ID
    }
    @foreach (var menuItem in Model.Header.TopLevelNavigation)
    {
        if (i < 6)
        {
            <li @Html.Raw(i > Model.MenuMidPoint ? "class=\"sub-menu-nudge-left\"" : "")>
                @if (menuItem.ContentLink.HasChildPages())
                {
                    <a href="#sub-menu-@i" class="menu-link js-ui-header-all-menu-drill-down" aria-haspopup="true">
                        <span class="icon icon-chevron-left @Model.GetBoxIcon(i)"></span>
                        <span>@menuItem.Name</span>
                    </a>
                    <div id="sub-menu-@i" class="sub-menu" aria-label="submenu" aria-hidden="true">
                        @Html.DisplayEnumerableIContent("<ul class=\"level-2 plain\">{0}</ul>", "<li>{0}</li>", "menu-link", menuItem.ContentLink.GetChildPages(true, true))
                    </div>
                }
            </li>
        }
        i++;
    }
</ul>
```

I tried the jquery function as below:
I tried as below, but I am unable to get the height of the submenu. It never gets into the foreach loop at all. Could anyone please help

```
$(".menu-link").click(function () {
var $subnavdev = $(this).parent().sublings('sub-menu').siblings('level-2 plain')
 var totalHeight = 0; 
    $subnavdev.find('li').each(function() {
      totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);
    });
    alert(totalHeight);
});
```

Comment: There is a typo: `sublings()` - Is this in your code, or a copy/paste artefact?

Comment: Also, you may want to refer to the class name? Use a `.` prefix: e.g. `.siblings('.sub-menu')...`

Answer (score 0):

Some of your class selectors were not specified correctly, plus there was a typographical error (all on Line 2).

**Update** - It also seems the `siblings()` methods may not be behaving as you intend them to...  - And I got the `.level-2` selector wrong still - since you need another `.` before `plain`. (See below example)

By using the `closest()` method you can go up to the nearest parent (for example, `<li>`), then use `find()` to pick out all .level-2.plain items nested within that parent.

Remember that your `$(this)` inside the handler function refers to the handled element, (in this case the `.menu-link` item being clicked.

```
$(".menu-link").click(function () {
   var $subnavdev = $(this).closest('li').find('.level-2.plain');
   // ...
});
```

Comment: I tried your code. It does not get into the for each loop at all.